# Xpath checking the amount of text input fields

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I am trying to write a phpUnit test in the Zend framework. And this time I for the fun want to test that I have two input fields of type **text** in my contact form.

So I wrote this line of code:

```
 $this->assertQueryCount('form#contact-form/input[@type="text"]',2);
```

But it returns:

> 1) IndexControllerTest::testCanDisplayContactForm
>   Failed asserting node DENOTED BY form#contact-form/input[type="text"] OCCURS EXACTLY 2 times

So I have a form with the id 'contact' form. And within this I want to get all the input fields of type **text**

Any idea's or tips?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@type` ? It being an attribute.

Comment: Yes I changed it but get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
form#contact-form/input[type="text"]
```

is more like jQuery selector syntax, it's not XPath. This is:

```
//form[@id = 'contact-form']/input[@type = 'text']
```

but what the `assertQueryCount()` function *actually* expects is a CSS selector:

```
form#contact-form input[type="text"]
```

Comment: I get this error: 1) IndexControllerTest::testCanDisplayContactForm
DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression

Comment: @sanders: The expression is valid XPath, that's for sure. If it does not work, then the `assertQueryCount()` does not really expect XPath (and a quick look into [the docs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Test/PHPUnit/Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase.html#assertQueryCount) reveals: a CSS selector is expected). See extended answer.

Comment: @sanders: The method that expect XPath expression is [`assertXpathCount`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Test/PHPUnit/Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase.html#assertXpathCount)